# Why it does not remove my employee object from employees array? (do not mind my methods)

Tags: c#

```
if (humanResourceManager.IsEmployeeExistByDepartmentNameAndNo(depname, employeeNo))
            {
                Employee employee = humanResourceManager.GetEmployeeExistByNo(employeeNo);
                Employee[] employees = humanResourceManager.GetDepartmentByName(depname).Employees;
                employee = null;
                Array.Sort(employees);
                Array.Reverse(employees);
                while (employees[employees.Length - 1] == null)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref employees, employees.Length - 1);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Silindi!");

                
            }
```

Comment: `Employee[] employees = humanResourceManager.GetDepartmentByName(depname).Employees.Where(z => z != employee).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Setting a variable to `null` does not change any other locations where the object is being referenced/used. See the following example:

```
string s = "abc";
string c = s;
string c = null;
```

This will not change the variable `s`, it still reference the string object `"abc"` (but the variable `c` now has the value `null`). The same goes for arrays:

```
string[] data = new string[] {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
string c = data[1];
string c = null;
```

Again, you are only changing the variable `c`, but you are not changing the array `data`. When you want to change the array you have to use the `data` array like this:

```
string[] data = new string[] {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
data[1] = null;
// the array is now: ["abc", null, "ghi"]
```

In your case, you have to change the `Employee[] employees` array. Depending on your code, you might need to use a method in `humanResourceManager` to update the source data where the array came from.